# Why does "Sum()" succeed where "+" fails in recursive R function?

Tags: r, function, recursion, functional-programming, operator-keyword

I am experimenting with the functional programming paradigm in R. I have defined a function that sums a sequence of integers from *n* to *m*. When I use `sum()` the function returns the expected result:

```
sumRange <- function(n, m) {
    if (n <= m) { 
        return(sum(n, sumRange((n + 1), m)))
    }
}

sumRange(1, 10)
# [1] 55
```

However, when I use the `+` operator the function returns `numeric(0)`:

```
sumRange <- function(n, m) {
    if (n <= m) {
        return(n + sumRange((n + 1), m))
    }
}

sumRange(1, 10)
# numeric(0)
```

Why does the operator `+` not work in this recursive function? Is there a way to rewrite the function so that it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you never specify an else condition, hence at the end of the recursion it appears that R is returning `NULL` when the `if` condition fails.  Returning 0 as the else condition fixes your problem:

```
sumRange <- function(n, m) return(ifelse (n <= m, (n +  sumRange((n+1), m)), 0))
sumRange(1, 10)
[1] 55
```

Note that this is essentially defining a *base case* for your recursion.  A base case, when hit, ends the recursion and causes the calls on the stack to be unwound.

To see the issue with the way you phrased your code, try writing out your function explicitly:

```
sumRange <- function(n, m) {
    if (n <= m) {
        return(n + sumRange((n+1), m))
    }
    // but what gets returned if n > m ?
    // this is undefined behavior
}
```

I'm not an R guru, but my understanding is that R was written in C, and C might allow a recursion like this with no `else` condition.  But the behavior is not well defined and you should not be relying on it.

## Demo

Comment: +1 for the base case. R functions do seem to return a  `NULL` object, if no return is available. So, may be it is well defined?

Comment: @Headpoint Choice of words.  Regardless off what R might return by default, the OP still never defined a base case, so an important part of the recursion most certainly is undefined.  And we should not be relying on this behavior when coding with R.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no return (using a explicit or implicit return statement) is executed, then R functions seems to return a `NULL` object.

If you add numerical value to a this object, it will simply return `numeric(0)`.

So, what happens in the second case is that when `n` reaches 11, it returns a `NULL` object, and goes back adding values to it. But `NULL + 10 + 9 .. = numeric(0)`.

Check this with

```
no_ret <- function ()
{
 # just return nothing
}

obj <- no_ret()
obj
# NULL 
class(obj)
# "NULL
new_obj <- obj + 10
new_obj
# numeric(0)
```

When the first function is executed, the what the sum statement get is
a vector with a `NULL` in it. For example, 
`vec <- c(NULL, 10, 9,...)` which is actually `vec <- c(10, 9, ...)`, so you get the expected outcome.

```
> c(NULL, 10:1)
 [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
> sum(NULL, 10:1)
[1] 55

> NULL + 10:1
integer(0)
```

Comment: I thought this "If there is no return statement is executed,..." covered that. I guess I would have written more on it expect you have already done so.